# TFS 2017.3: Deployment approvers page customization

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a way to add a custom field with drop-down values in the TFS 2017.3 environment approves screen? (like we can add a custom field in Work Items)

Comment: What do you want to add? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add a field with drop down value on the Deployment approver page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of doing this. With that I mean, there is no easy option in the UI to add this and no commandline tool that can do it either.

That said, the web UI in Visual Studio is highly customizable and extensible. There are extension points just about everywhere and I'd be surprised if it were impossible to extend this area, but that is a whole different kind of ballgame. The documentation for custom UI controls explains in general how to add your extensions to the UI.

You may also have to rely on Service Hooks or Release Gates to hold off the release until your custom fields have been filled correctly. I don't think there is a place to store these details, so you'll need to provide that as well.

```
TL;DR
```

No, unless you want to build a custom extension.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation , so it seems that a Custom extension can only help in this.... are there any steps you can share to make this happen appreciate your help!